# An idea to shorten the code, the code works well but must shorten it with a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you see the working code I uploaded a link But I need to create for LOOP Because at the moment I only have 3 items in an Array And I have a code that adds every click to an item Unnamed: That's why I need you friends. Someone has an idea I was looking here for LOOP but there is information I already know And I need a LOOP that creates a VAR with something like var val[i] = $ ("# singel"[i]); https://jsfiddle.net/iandslevi/6uew8fqu/1/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

            #singels{
                background-color: #bfbfbf;
                color: #ffff33;
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;

            }

        </style>
    </head>

<body>




            <div id="singels">
                <form action="index.php" method="post"><ul style="list-style-type: none;"></ul><input type="submit" value="Place Bet" name="submit"></form>
            </div>



        <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function (){
var singelsvalue = ["2","3","4"];
var singel = ["test1","test2","test3"];

if (singelsvalue.length !== 0)
{
    // var someSingel = "0";
    if(someSingel = "undefinted"){someSingel = "0"}
    if(someSingel1 = "undefinted"){someSingel1 = "0"}

        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            $("#singel0").keyup( function(){
            var val0 = $("#singel0").val();
            var someSingel0 = val0 * singelsvalue[0];
            $("#span0").text(someSingel0.toFixed(2));
            someSingel0 = someSingel0 * val0;
            });

                $("#singel1").keyup( function(){
                var val1 = $("#singel1").val();
                var someSingel1 = val1 * singelsvalue[1];
                $("#span1").text(someSingel1.toFixed(2));
                someSingel1 = someSingel1 * val1;
                });

                    $("#singel2").keyup( function(){
                    var val2 = $("#singel2").val();
                    var someSingel2 = val2 * singelsvalue[2];
                    $("#span2").text(someSingel2.toFixed(2));
                    someSingel2 = someSingel2 * val2;
                    });                    
        });



        for(i=0; i<singel.length ; i++)
        {
            var someSingel = someSingel[i];
            if(someSingel = "undefinted"){someSingel = "0"}
            $("#singels form ul").append("<li>"+ singel[i] + " " + singelsvalue[i]+  " x " +'<input id="singel'+i+'" name="singel" type="text" placeholder="stake"><p>To Return :<span id="span'+i+'">'+ someSingel +'<span></p></li>');
        }


}
});

</script>



 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the specific issue? Create a loop, the selector is a string concatenation, etc. It's not clear to me yet why you need individual variables rather than a collection of values.

Comment: look at all selector $("#singel0"),$("#singel1"),$("#singel2")   ineed find an for loop for this i can all item in array write like what i have now but i hope i can find a for loop for this.